# Swap Ctrl with a character key in xkb

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm currently trying to remap my H key (`<AC06>`) to act like the Ctrl key.

I added the following in the /usr/.../xkb/symbols/us file:

```
key <AC06> { [ Control_L, Control_L ] };
```

It seemed to work as programs that have a different behavior when Ctrl is down (like Chrome) recognised the key as Ctrl. But when used in conjunction with any other key (ctrl-T for example, or H-T here) it did not work.

I also tried to add `partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys` in front of the `xkb_symbols` declaration and to add `replace key <AC06>...` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

All I had to add was the following line:

```
modifier_map Control { <AC06> };        `
```

But now I'm having issues as GNOME seems to think that H is still Ctrl (and H at the same time!) while in other layouts (I was modifying colemak but it had an impact on other layouts too)...

Comment: Why does modifying one layout affect the others? I am experiencing a similar issue.